# Filter Values by Levenshtein Distance in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two Array with Addresses in there. I want to filter duplicates by levenshtein distance.

```
$addresses1  = array (
    new Address("Company1", "Person1","Sirname1","Street One", "1", "11111", "City 1"), 
    new Address("Company1", "Person3","Sirname2","Street Two", "17", "22222", "City 2"),
    new Address("Company2", "Person6","Sirname6","Street Three", "11", "33333", "City 3"),);

$addresses2  = array (
    new Address("Company1", "Person1","Sirname1","Street One", "1", "11111", "City 1"), 
    new Address("Company4", "Person7","Sirname7","Street Five", "5", "55555", "City 5"),
    new Address("Company3", "Person3","Sirname3","Street Six", "6", "66666", "City 6"));

function compare ($array1, $array2){
    $uniqueArray = array();
    foreach($array1 as $k1 => $v1) {
        foreach($array2 as $k2 => $v2) {
            $levenshteinCompany = levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany());
            print_r ($levenshteinCompany);
            if ($levenshteinCompany > 0 ){
                $uniqueArray[] = $v1;
                $uniqueArray[] = $v2;
                unset($array2[$k2]);
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($uniqueArray);
}`
```

But I have 3 times company1 in my uniqueArray.

Comment: How are you limiting it using the levenshtein function?  Are you using an arbitrary distance?

Comment: im using the return values of the php function. im not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Company1 is showing up three times in the two arrays.  So it shows up at least once when you put $v1 in unique array.  Then it shows up again when it is compared to Company4 and again when it is compared to Company3.
My suggestion is to do an

```
if(!isset($uniqueArray[$v1]) 
    $uniqueArray[$v1] = $v1;
if(!isset($uniqueArray[$v2])
    $uniqueArray[$v2] = $v2;
```

This will return an associative array like this

```
$uniqueArray = "Company1" => "Company1",  "Company3" => "Company3", .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `'company1'` in your `$uniqueArray` 3 times because of how you're aggregating the values into your array.

Let's pretend I'm your function and you're telling me to compare all of the values from `$array1` with each value from `$array2`.  You pass me 'company1' from `$array1` and tell me to compare it to 'company1', 'company4' and 'company3' from `$array2`.

```
// iteration 1:1
//          'company1',        'company1'
levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany()) // 0

// iteration 1:2
//          'company1',        'company4'
levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany()) // 1

// iteration 1:3
//          'company1',        'company3'
levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany()) // 1

// iteration 2:1
//          'company1',        'company1'
levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany()) // 0

// iteration 3:1
//          'company2',        'company1'
levenshtein($v1->getCompany(), $v2->getCompany()) // 1
```

The first time through the loop comparing 'company1' to 'company1' will get 0.  Then it compares 'company1' to 'company4' and gets 1.  So I add it to `$uniqueArray`.

Your code:

```
$uniqueArray[] = $v1;
$uniqueArray[] = $v2;
```

Right now, this is what `$uniqueArray` looks like:

```
array(
    'company1',
    'company4'
);
```

Next, we compare 'company1' to 'company3' and get 1 again, so we add them into `$uniqueArray` again.  Now `$uniqueArray` will look like this:

```
array(
    'company1',
    'company4',
    'company1',
    'company3'
);
```

And we proceed to the second iteration of your first loop.  Since you're telling me to unset elements from `$array2` whenever there's a match, the only element left in `$array2` is 'company1'.  So now we compare the second element of `$array1` (which is 'company1' again) with 'company1' from `$array2`.  No matches will be found, so we proceed to the third and final iteration of the first loop.

Now you're having me compare 'company2' from `$array1[2]` to 'company1' from `$array1`.  This will result in 1.  So you add them to the `$uniqueArray` again.  By the end, your array will look like:

```
array(
    'company1',
    'company4',
    'company1',
    'company3',
    'company1',
    'company2'
);
```

---

Instead, change your logic to this:

```
if ($levenshteinCompany > 0) {
    $uniqueArray[$v1][] = $v2;
    unset($array2[$k2]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your extensively answer! 
I have change my logic to your advice but im getting an illegal offset and an empty array returned.

`if ($levenshteinCompany > 0 ){
              $uniqueArray[$v1][] = $v2;   
              unset($array2[$k2]);
    }`